# Full Sidebar show on hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frameworks, web, stack-overflow

I'm working on a sidebar on my website. I'm using bootstrap framework.
I created a sidebar but now i need to hover it. I'm looking something like Facebooks new sidebar. Can anyone help me from this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUS6o.jpg

Answer (score 0):

> [Here](http://www.quackit.com/css/codes/css_floating_menu.cfm) you will find code for a CSS floating menu bar, also known
>   as "fixed menus" and "hovering menus", floating menus stay in a fixed
>   position when you scroll the page. They appear to "float" on top of
>   the page as you scroll.

Hope that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks man, but I'm Looking for somethings like this >> http://i.stack.imgur.com/yMLRY.png , I fixed the position but when I hover the sidebar only sidebar moving the body stay in the same position..sorry for my English..;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bootstrap resource that will help you achieve the "drawer" style menu (float out from the left) - http://tech.xtremelabs.com/html5-facebook-style-sliding-menu-using-twitter-bootstrap-collapse/